# Android Studio release installation fails, error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: java, android

Im making an android app in Android Studio which works fine when im debugging it on my phone but crashes when I download it from Google play and it doesnt work either if I try to install it on my phone in release mode.
When i try to install in release mode I get the following error:

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Although I build signed APKs and App Bunndles
Could you help me what could possibly be the solution?